# Changing indices and order in arrays

Tags: arrays, matlab, struct, indexing

I have a struct `mpc` with the following structure:

```
          num  type    col3    col4 ...
mpc.bus =   1     2     ...    ...
            2     2     ...    ...
            3     1     ...    ...
            4     3     ...    ...
            5     1     ...    ...
           10     2     ...    ...
           99     1     ...    ...

             to from   col3   col4 ...
mpc.branch =  1    2    ...    ...
              1    3    ...    ...
              2    4    ...    ... 
             10    5    ...    ...
             10   99    ...    ...
```

What I need to do is:
1: Re-order the rows of `mpc.bus`, such that all rows of type `1` are first, followed by `2` and at last, `3`. There is only one element of type `3`, and no other types (`4 / 5` etc.).

2: Make the numbering (column 1 of `mpc.bus`, consecutive, starting at 1.

3: Change the numbers in the to-from columns of `mpc.branch`, to correspond to the new numbering in `mpc.bus`.

4: After running simulations, reverse the steps above to turn up with the same order and numbering as above.

It is easy to update `mpc.bus` using `find`.

```
type_1 = find(mpc.bus(:,2) == 1);
type_2 = find(mpc.bus(:,2) == 2);
type_3 = find(mpc.bus(:,2) == 3);

mpc.bus(:,:) = mpc.bus([type1; type2; type3],:);
mpc.bus(:,1) = 1:nb   % Where nb is the number of rows of mpc.bus
```

The numbers in the to/from columns in `mpc.branch` corresponds to the numbers in column 1 in `mpc.bus`.

It's OK to update the numbers on the `to`, `from` columns of `mpc.branch` as well.

However, I'm not able to find a non-messy way of retracing my steps. Can I update the numbering using some simple commands?

For the record: I have deliberately not included my code for re-numbering mpc.branch, since I'm sure someone has a smarter, simpler solution (that will make it easier to redo when the simulations are finished).

**Edit**: It might be easier to create normal arrays (to avoid woriking with structs):

```
bus = mpc.bus;
branch = mpc.branch;
```

**Edit #2**: The order of things:

1. Re-order and re-number.
2. Columns (3:end) of `bus` and `branch` are changed. (Not part of this question)
3. Restore original order and indices.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I'm proposing this solution. It generates a `n x 2` matrix, where `n` corresponds to the number of rows in `mpc.bus` and a temporary copy of `mpc.branch`:

```
function [mpc_1, mpc_2, mpc_3] = minimal_example

mpc.bus = [ 1     2;...
            2     2;...
            3     1;...
            4     3;...
            5     1;...
           10     2;...
           99     1];

mpc.branch = [ 1    2;...
               1    3;...
               2    4;...
              10    5;...
              10   99];

mpc.bus = sortrows(mpc.bus,2);

mpc_1 = mpc;

mpc_tmp = mpc.branch;

for I=1:size(mpc.bus,1)
    PAIRS(I,1) = I;
    PAIRS(I,2) = mpc.bus(I,1);
    mpc.branch(mpc_tmp(:,1:2)==mpc.bus(I,1)) = I;
    mpc.bus(I,1) = I;
end

mpc_2 = mpc;
% (a) the following mpc_tmp is only needed if you want to truly reverse the operation
mpc_tmp = mpc.branch; 

%
% do some stuff
%

for I=1:size(mpc.bus,1)
    % (b) you can decide not to use the following line, then comment the line below (a)
    mpc.branch(mpc_tmp(:,1:2)==mpc.bus(I,1)) = PAIRS(I,2);
    mpc.bus(I,1) = PAIRS(I,2);
end

% uncomment the following line, if you commented (a) and (b) above:
% mpc.branch = mpc_tmp;

mpc.bus = sortrows(mpc.bus,1);

mpc_3 = mpc;
```

The minimal example above can be executed as is. The three outputs (`mpc_1`, `mpc_2` & `mpc_3`) are just in place to demonstrate the workings of the code but are otherwise not necessary.

1.) `mpc.bus` is ordered using `sortrows`, simplifying the approach and not using `find` three times. It targets the second column of `mpc.bus` and sorts the remaining matrix accordingly.
2.) The original contents of `mpc.branch` are stored.
3.) A loop is used to replace the entries in the first column of `mpc.bus` with ascending numbers while at the same time replacing them correspondingly in `mpc.branch`. Here, the reference to `mpc_tmp` is necessary so ensure a correct replacement of the elements.
4.) Afterwards, `mpc.branch` can be reverted analogously to (3.) - here, one might argue, that if the original `mpc.branch` was stored earlier on, one could just copy the matrix. Also, the original values of `mpc.bus` are re-assigned.
5.) Now, `sortrows` is applied to `mpc.bus` again, this time with the first column as reference to restore the original format.

Comment: Thanks! I think this is going to work! The reason why I used `find` instead of `sortrows` is because I'm actually arranging it: `2 1 3` and not `1 2 3` (that part is easy to fix though). I was hoping to avoid loops, but I guess that will be hard in this case.

Thanks again, I can definitely use this =)

(I'll keep the question open a little longer in case someone has a clever "quick-fix". If not I'll accept your answer tomorrow =) )

Comment: @Jack : If come up with a less-loops/loop-free idea, I'll edit my answer.